# Digital clock in website

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Can anyone please explain me how to put a digital clock in my jsp page. I have to put two clock one for India and one for Switzerland.

How can this be possible ?

Comment: And what have you tried? What went wrong? Why do you think it's *not* possible?

Comment: Sorry I havent tried anything just asking question for answer ....from next time i will try first and then post my question ....and it was a great blog :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website has a tutorial on using the Date.getTimezoneOffset() method which you'll be able to use to define the clock locally.

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

India is easy- one time zone for the whole country, and no daylight savings time.

India time is UTC+05:30.

Sweden observes dst between 2:00 am on the last Sunday in March and 3:00 am the last Sunday in October.

Sweden's offsets are UTC+1:00 during standard time, UTC+2:00 during dst.

Be sure to apply the dst changes in Sweden's time, which is easy to calculate from UTC.